# Querying and totaling certian elements in a list

Tags: python, list

So I am very new to python and I have created a list of information that looks like this:

the format is Date, Store, Total income(in that day) and transactions(in that day)

```
data = [[datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 1, 0), 'PizzaHut', 2839.60, 25], [datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 4, 0), 'Dominoes', 2839.60, 25], [datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 8, 0), 'Sals', 2839.60, 25], [datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 4, 0), 'Sals', 2839.60, 25], [datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 12, 0), 'PizzaHut', 2839.60, 25]
```

So essentially what I am trying do is to query to total income of the a certain store. so the user should enter for example 'Sals' and it will total up the income of that store based on the data in the list. There is probably a really simple solution to the problem but I have been looking around on the net and decided it was time for me to ask you guys. if I can get some explanation on how it works that would really help me aswell as it helps me to grow my knowledge! Thank you all for your contributions!

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/  - being new to python - and even to programming - is not an excuse to not at least give it a try (and no, "looking around the net" is NOT "giving a try").

Comment: I never said I didn't give it a try? Of course I did I tried different solutions for a long time and couldn't find anything that did what I wanted it to. So I decided that it was time to ask the helpful community at Stackoverflow :)

Comment: I'm not not talking about "solutions" that you've "been looking around on the net". If _you_ did try something _by yourself_ then you should have posted your attempt and explained what problems you had with it, not asking for a ready-made solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sum()`

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
data = [[datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 1, 0), 'PizzaHut', 2839.60, 25], [datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 4, 0), 'Dominoes', 2839.60, 25], [datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 8, 0), 'Sals', 2839.60, 25], [datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 4, 0), 'Sals', 2839.60, 25], [datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 12, 0), 'PizzaHut', 2839.60, 25]]
key = 'Sals'

print( sum(i[2] for i in data if i[1] == key) )
```

**Output:**

```
5679.2
```

*Edit as per comment*

```
import datetime
import collections
data = [[datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 1, 0), 'PizzaHut', 2839.60, 25], [datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 4, 0), 'Dominoes', 2839.60, 25], [datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 8, 0), 'Sals', 2839.60, 25], [datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 4, 0), 'Sals', 2839.60, 25], [datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 12, 0), 'PizzaHut', 2839.60, 25]]
key = 'Sals'

d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for i in data:
    d[i[1]].append(i)

print( "Sum: {0}".format(sum(i[2] for i in d[key])) )
print( "Average: {0}".format(sum(i[2] for i in d[key])/len(d[key])) )
```

**Output:**

```
Sum: 5679.2
Average: 2839.6
```

*Group-By Date*

```
key = datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 4, 0)

d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for i in data:
    d[i[0]].append(i)
```

Comment: Awesome! How would I calculate an average of the stores sales as well then? Cheers :)

Comment: @Jasotufy2 To calculate the average just do `print(sum([i[2] for i in data if i[1] == 'Sals'])/len([i for i in data if i[1] == 'Sals']))`

Comment: Okay so one more question... If I wanted to use the date instead of the branch name to query results how could I do that?

Comment: Just change the key to your required date ex: `key = datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 4, 0)` and this line `d[i[1]].append(i)` to `d[i[0]].append(i)`

Comment: Still not really getting it to work to well :( could you post it in the code for me please. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I would build a dictionary if searches be frequent.

```
res = {}
def builddict(data):
  for ele in data:
    res.setdefault(ele[1], 0)
    res[ele[1]] += ele[2] * ele[3]

builddict(data)
print (res['Sals'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) to make your code more readable:

```
import datetime

from collections import namedtuple

dailySales = namedtuple('Data', ['day', 'store', 'income', 'transactions'])

data = [[datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 1, 0), 'PizzaHut', 2839.60, 25],
        [datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 4, 0), 'Dominoes', 2839.60, 25],
        [datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 8, 0), 'Sals', 2839.60, 25],
        [datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 4, 0), 'Sals', 2839.60, 25],
        [datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 12, 0), 'PizzaHut', 2839.60, 25]]

namedData = [dailySales(*i) for i in data]

key = 'Sals'

print(sum(j.income for j in namedData if j.store==key))
#5679.2
```